# Asymptotic behavior of hypergeometric function ${}_{3}F_{2}(a,b-n,c-n;d-n,e-n;1)$ for $n\to\infty$

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

Suppose $a,b,c,d,e\in\mathbb{R}$ are such that $d+e-a-b-c>0$ and $d,e\notin\mathbb{Z}$. I would like to know whether it is possible to deduce an asymptotic formula for the sequence given by the hypergeometric function
$$
 {}_{3}F_{2}(a,b-n,c-n;d-n,e-n;1), \quad \mbox{ for }\; n\to\infty.
$$
Let me remark that I have checked DLMF as well as monographs on special functions by Bailey; Prudnikov, Brychkov, Marichev; and Erdelyi but have not found the answer.

Comment: Did you try to use the three-term transformation ((3.1.3) in Gasper and Rahman, Basic hypergeometric series)? Then you will get a sum of two ${}_3F_2$-series that only have two parameters depending on $n$ instead of four. Formally they tend to summable  ${}_2F_1$-series when $n\rightarrow\infty$ and perhaps this will allow you to get a hand on the asymptotics.

Comment: @HjalmarRosengren I haven't tried this approach. Thank you for the comment.